# Can I write it in remix ide?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, dynamic-arrays, remix

I made a dynamic array variable of **address type,** i.e.,

```
address payable[] public participant;
```

which one is the correct way to write in the following and why,

```
uint payable[] public participant;
```

or

```
uint[] payable public participant;



enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `address` and its extension `address payable`, which allows you to use the native `transfer()` method to send ETH to this address.

Since the type is called `address payable`, you can make an array of this type by appending the `[]` expression after the type name.

There's no `payable` extension to `uint`. If your aim is to define an amount to be sent, that can be stored in a regular `uint`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    address payable[] public participants;

    function foo() public {
        uint amount = 1; // 1 wei
        for (uint i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
            participants[i].transfer(amount);
        }
    }
}
```